Why was my question closed? Please reopen
I posted this question How to map several folders to different drive?
It got closed as a duplicate of Move home folder to second drive, but the duplicate is certainly not the same. The dup is about moving folders to separate partitions. My question is about moving several folders to one partition.
Is it an honest mistake, or is there something I'm missing?

I believe the dupe answers your question admirably

@graham According to the comment section, the user emk2203 seem to disagree with you.

I also agree that the question is different than the suggested dupe and voted to reopen it.

@BeastOfCaerbannog doesn't it it behove the OP to explain why the dupe is different? I don't see that having been done.

@graham For me it's clear that the OP already knows how to have single system files (such as /home) to respective partitions, which is what the suggested dupe is about, but wants to know how to have multiple system files to a single partition, which the suggested dupe doesn't talk about.

The OP has also explained that in this meta question: "It got closed as a duplicate of Move home folder to second drive, but the duplicate is certainly not the same. The dup is about moving folders to separate partitions. My question is about moving several folders to one partition."
